# Why Cardinality not the same for rounded floats?

Tags: floating-point

I need to solve a question:

> Two float values are equivalent if they return same integer with `Math.round()`. Why the equivalence classes arising from this equivalence relationship does not have the same cardinality?

I was thinking that cardinality is the same as you can have infinitely many numbers which would round up to the same class... For example 3.11 and 3.1111 or 3.2222 and so on would all return 3 and this could be done with any float value.

Comment: I think you are confusing mathematics with computer science: there are only **finitely** many float values

Comment: True, but question indicates "arising from this equivalence relationship" so I think we do not consider the values which float does not contain

Comment: Does it mean that where the boundaries are, the cardinality will be lower?

Comment: The question basically asks "Why are there more floats which round to $0$ than to $1000$?"

Comment: How many round to $1e50$?

Comment: @Arthur Could you explain why class of 0 will have biggest cardinality?

Comment: @Augustas Because basically half of all floats are between $-0.5$ and $0.5$.

Comment: @Arhur Sorry, could you please send me a link where I could read about that because I do not find about it any info on the Internet.

Comment: are you saying that the amount of float value between 9.5 and 10.5 is not the same as between -0.5 and 0.5?

Comment: I got it, thanks

Comment: "are you saying that the amount of float value between 9.5 and 10.5 is not the same as between -0.5 and 0.5?" Yes, that's exactly what I'm saying, and your original problem asks you to explain why that may be. They are doing that in a roundabout way, talking about equivalence classes and rounding, but that is what they are asking you.